# Access client secret (Azure AD auth) from app settings .net 6 app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, appsettings, azure-appservice

I have a .net 6 app using azure ad for authentication. Below are the details:

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-oidc"
    "ClientSecret": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykv.vault.azure.net/secrets/myclientsecret/)"
```

Program.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
                            .AddDownstreamApi("MyService", Configuration.GetSection("MyService")); //MyService is also present in appsetting with baseurl and scopes
```

The app is deployed in app service and  has the following app setting:
Name: AzureAd__ClientSecret
Value: @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykv.vault.azure.net/secrets/myclientsecret/)

I expect the ClientSecret value read from keyvault and the rest to be read from the appsettings json. How can I make this happen? If I hardcode client secret in appsetting it works. I am struggling to understand why this is not allowing sign in?

Also RedirectURI has been added.

Snap of App Service Configuration

[image]

Comment: Hello Community, Please let me know if I need to add any additional information

Comment: I also tried to move all the settings from json file to app service (Configuration) (for e.g. AzureAd:Instance) and I am not using Id instead of value like I have seen in multiple posts

Comment: You are using [Key Vault Reference for App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli). That means the web app you published to should be able to access that azure key vault instance, I mean you need to add access policy for the web app in key vault. Then you also need to make sure your web app had authorized first, following the document will bring to to use managed identity, so that you app can get authorized to access key vault. Have you set managed identity and added access policy?

Comment: @TinyWang Thank you for responding to my query. Yes I have turned on system assigned managed identity for my app and it has the Key Vault Secret User role assigned.

Comment: Few more details: I have appsettings.json, appsettings.Test.json. I have created ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to be Test for the app service to pick appsettings.Test.json. If I add ClientSecret with hardcoded value in appsettings.Test and have the app setting in Configuration: AzureAd:ClientSecret it works. If I remove the app setting from Configuration it fails. If I keep app setting in configuration but remove from code it fails.

Comment: Could you paste a snip of the configuration in the Azure App Service?

Comment: @Rukmini Added in the question

Comment: I deleted all my app setting file and now have just the appsettings.json which should be picked up on deployment. It is still not able to perform authentication. I was thinking of trying other ways to get the app setting loaded for e.g. variable group and use my template to have all the settings but if it is not picking up from the app setting file itself how will it work if I try anything else? It seems to only work if I hard code the secret value which I do not wish to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iam able to authenticate and login even without the Client Secret.

> I expect the ClientSecret value read from keyvault and the rest to be read from the appsettings json.

I have set the key `ClientSecret` without any value in `appsettings.json` file.

My `appsettings.json`:

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "*****.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "**********",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "KeyVault": {
    "URI": "https://HarshuKV8June.vault.azure.net/"
  }
}
```

My `.csproj` file:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication2-f96bb6f0-eef0-4193-a9b3-6a006134f076</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.16" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.16" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***Use the below code to retrieve the Client Secret from Azure Key Vault.***

Use, any one line of below code to retrieve teh secret value from KeyVault.

```cs
var ClientSecret = secretClient.GetSecret("ClientSecret").Value.Value;
```

***OR***

```cs
var secretValue = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("ClientSecret");
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using System.ComponentModel;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var KV = builder.Configuration["KeyVault:URI"];
var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(KV), cred);

var ClientSecret = secretClient.GetSecret("ClientSecret").Value.Value;
var secretValue = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("ClientSecret");

//Setting the ClientSecret to the key in `appsettings.json` file
builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"] = ClientSecret;

//Retrieving the value from `appsettings.json` file
var setClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAD:ClientSecret");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{   
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");  
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***ClientSecret Value from KeyVault:***

[image]

***Redirect URI in AAD:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***Localhost:***
[image]

***Deployed App:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Harshitha! The above example works. Also in my case with your reference to program cs I loaded environment vars at the end which resolved my issue, earlier it was before app settings were loaded using add json.