# Azure Key Vault "Reference Syntax" Does Nothing

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, configuration, azure-keyvault

I have a Web API project in .NET 7.0, which deploys to Azure as an App Service, and which uses an Azure KeyVault for secrets.

I am currently trying to access a KeyVault secret from `appsettings.json` using the "reference syntax":

```
"TESTKEY": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<my_kv_url>/secrets/TESTKEY)"
```

Now if I run my code and put a breakpoint in `Program.cs` to interrogate the config values, the returned string is always exactly what is shown above; it is not resolved by .NET/Azure.

I added a dummy end-point to my API to return the value of `TESTKEY`, so I can see if it is resolved once deployed, but the result is exactly the same.

The App Service uses a System Managed Identity with adequate roles assigned. I don't believe this is an auth issue however, since I can access the KeyVault (both locally and live) by using `AddAzureKeyVault`. It's just the "reference syntax" that doesn't work.

I've also looked at the logs both locally and live, and there are no errors or warnings. I don't think any attempt is being made to resolve the reference at all.

I went over Microsoft's instructions several times (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli), and did search around for existing answers to this question, but couldn't find anyone (who had been answered) with the same set of circumstances as me.

Would massively appreciate any help at all- thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that syntax only works in the App Service's app settings (not the file, configuration in Portal/through Bicep/ARM/Terraform).

Comment: @Oliver Nicholls I had something similar and it got resolved. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383437/access-client-secret-azure-ad-auth-from-app-settings-net-6-app/76428960#76428960   Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. @juunas You're right. It worked when I added the reference to the App Service config (and gave it a few minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key Vault references only work when added to the App Service's configuration, not within the application's configuration files.
The App Service resolves them and gives them to your app as environment variables, same as other settings in the configuration.