# Azure Service authentication in Visual Studio 2022 works even after sign out

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project. In this project I'm using `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets`'s `SecretClient` class to fetch secrets from a key vault.

I'm able to fetch the secrets from key vault when I signed in into Visual Studio using my personal Microsoft account as well as without sign in into Visual Studio. I wanted to know how `SecretClient` class authenticates the user? How it is able to get Azure AD token to authenticate itself with Azure key vault to retrieve secret even without signing into Visual Studio?

Below is the code I have used in `Program.cs` (.NET 6) file to inject the `SecretClient` dependency:

```
using backendapp.Services.Contracts;
using backendapp.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using backendapp.Services.Repository;

namespace backendapp;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddAzureClients(azureClientFactoryBuilder =>
        {
            azureClientFactoryBuilder.AddSecretClient(builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault"));
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultManager, KeyVaultManager>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClientWrapper, DocumentClientWrapper>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDbManager, DbManager>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Also in `appsettings.json`, I have a section `KeyVault` which has just a `VaultUri` entry.

Below is my `KeyVaultManager` class which uses the `SecretClient` class

```
    public class KeyVaultManager : IKeyVaultManager
    {
        private SecretClient _secretClient;

        public KeyVaultManager(SecretClient secretClient)
        {
            _secretClient = secretClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
        {
            try
            {
                KeyVaultSecret keyVaultSecret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
                return keyVaultSecret.Value;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know how I'm able to fetch secrets from keyvault under my personal account even without signing in to Visual Studio.
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your complete `Program.cs` file.

Comment: @Harshitha I have added the complete Program.cs file.

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76428960/19648279) to fetch secrets from key vault and check whether you are able to retrieve even without signin.

Comment: Yes I'm able to access without signin after trying this

Comment: Are you sure you have logged out from all the accounts in VS.Verify it in the options => accounts section

Comment: I have verified this under azure service authentication. Attached a screenshot for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254235/discussion-between-harshitha-and-pulkit-sharma).

Comment: Azure authentication will try different authentication mechanisms in order to authenticate.
From what I see, I would assume you are using AzureDefaultCredentials. Consult the [AzureDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential) documentation to see the possible mechanisms. If I had to guess, I would say you are still logged in with Azur CLI.

Comment: @Silva thanks for your answer. I was logged in with Azure CLI. After running az logout I was not able to access the secrets.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer to close this question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure authentication utilizes various methods to authenticate with Azure services, attempting them in a specific order.

You can check out the [AzureDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true#defaultazurecredential) documentation to see the different mechanisms and the sequence in which they are tried.

It is very likely that you are still logged in with Azure Cli.